# selecting elements from a column based on a range of indices listed in another column on Excel

Tags: excel, list, range, subtraction

Not sure if this the right place, but let's say I have a column C of entries and another column D of certain indices of the elements in C. Now, if I wanted to select only those elements in C that correspond to these indices, how would I be able to do so, in order to subtract each corresponding value from values of another column?
For example : D is a list with {100,231,567,789,911} representing the row numbers of elements in column C and I wanted to select, in another column, just these elements; subtract them one at a time, from values of another column, say E.